# The part of the motor that the hobbed gear goes on is too short

Tags: creality-ender-3, replacement-parts

My Ender 3 had a broken part so I replaced all the plastic above the extruder motor.

After learning how to safely take off the pressure-fitted hobbed gear, I installed a new one that could be replaced more easily. Now the teeth of the gear are too low to reach the PLA. The rest looks fine, I've tried flipping it upside down (the squeezy handle won't fit) and I've tried moving it as high up as I can. Do I have to buy a new motor with a longer rod? (sorry I don't know the names of these things)

As previously mentioned, the gear has already been replaced. It's not stuck and I now have one with screws (its the one in the picture)

[image: Photo of the Creality metal extruder with the brass hobbed gear too low to reach the filament]

Comment: Can you show a picture? That might help assess what's wrong.

Comment: As stated above, please [edit] your question and upload an image

Comment: Pretty sure you just have it on upside down.

Answer (score 1):

So, as mentioned, you could get a new stepper motor. As an alernative, have you tried flipping the hobbed gear around (as shown in this picture)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question [Problems with stock gear with no screw on Ender 3 pro](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15131/problems-with-stock-gear-with-no-screw-on-ender-3-pro/16030), more specifically [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/16030/) and [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/15285/) describe that after changing the gear, the shaft is too short. It is advised to just buy a replacement stepper or tap the shaft from the bottom of the stepper to extend the shaft. First option is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: I don't need to remove any gears.

Comment: According to your question `After learning how to safely take off the pressure-fitted hobbed gear, I installed a new one that could be replaced more easily.` you did...